# Which kernel that make image brighter or darker?

Tags: image-processing

Below is the list of kernel

Kernel A

[image: Image of Kernel A]

Kernel B

[image: Image of Kernel B]

Kernel C

[image: Image of Kernel C]

I know that Kernel A is a low pass filter which is for blurring, but B and C are high pass filter.

High pass filter is for making image sharper but how to identify between B and C

that can make image brighter or darker?

Comment: Wouldn't Kernel C increase the overall frequency of the image (|3| > |-2|), causing it to be brighter?

Answer (score 0):

Your question seems a little confusing.  What I would do is simply run them on an image and see the difference.  http://setosa.io/ev/image-kernels/ has one that you can play with.

It looks like Kernal B makes the image quite dark and Kernel C seems to sharpen it.  Does that help?

Comment: I have a feeling you are right. But I am just to lazy to try it out LOL !!

Answer (score 0):

You should try it on your own actually haha.

The simple answer is **B kernel will return Darker images**. Meanwhile, the **C kernel returns a brighter image**.

I've tried to convolve each kernel and return histogram such as:

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xtS5F.png)